# visual studio 2019 keeps asking to save project file as after adding new file or updating nuget files

Tags: tfs, checkout

I moved to a new machine and now I am having this any time I want to update a nuget package in my project or add a new file.  What is weird, is when VS attempts to check out the file (Using DevOps TFS for source control), the project file gets deleted, and this is why I think the system is prompting me to save the project.  But what's weird, is it will not let me save it to the original location, in fact, it won't let me save it anywhere on my drive.  I full rights to that path where I am working in, so I don't believe it's user rights.  I am doing a repair right now, so we will see where this goes.    I have looked at a few threats already out there and tried what they asked, but that didn't help either or was not the solution.  I am hoping someone else has had this issue and can help me out.   It really bothers me that VS is physically deleting the CSPROJ file when it checks it out. If you need to know more information, let me know.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2019, the csproj will not be displayed in the Solution Explorer.

The reason for why it doesn't let you to save it may be that the csproj already exist, you can't save the file with same name.

You could create a xml outside VS and copy the content of csproj to make a backup
.
You could edit csproj by double click the project name, select Edit Project File or check the workspace locally to confirm if the csproj already exists even if it is not displayed in the VS.
[image]